# How can I update the field of the entity?

Tags: entities, 8, database

I have an "Question" entity, and I need to updates its 'key' field (of string type):

My code isn't working:

```
  $storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('question');
  $query = $storage->getQuery();
  $query
          ->condition('key', $key);

  $entity = $query->execute();


 $entity -> set ('key', 'new_value');
 $entity->save();
```

It returns the error Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object

Answer (score 2):

The [QueryInterface::execute()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Query!QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Aexecute/8.2.x) method returns either an integer or an array, not an object. It is a good idea to check api.drupal.org (if you don't use an IDE), or let your IDE do the work for you with intellisense.

It probably would be easier to use [loadByProperties](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x), which loads the entities for you. However it is definitely useful to get the query object, but you need to call [loadMultiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadMultiple/8.2.x).

```
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('question')
  ->loadByProperties(['key' => $key]);

if (!empty($entities)) {
  $entity = reset($entities);
  $entity->set('key', 'new_value');
  $entity->save();
}
```